# how to use newly added fields from addFields stage in the next match stage in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I'd like to take weekly, hourly report of data based on date field from mongodb, for doing so, have tried to add new field called "difference" using addFields stage before the match stage and then try to use that "difference" date field in the match stage as dynamic value for the condition against the existing date field called "createdDate".

But am getting all data as output instead of expected data for only periodic dates(difference of 7 days)

***sample doc from the collection:***

```
{
"name":"Gold",
"age":20,
createdDate : ISODate("2023-05-03T12:36:02.719Z")
}
```

***Query:***

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {$addFields:{difference:{$subtract:[new Date(),7*24*60*60*1000]}}},
    {$match:{createdDate:{$gte:"$difference"}}}
    ]);
```

Any suggestion pls?

Comment: You would need to use `$expr` in the `$match` to achieve this. But rather than taking this approach I'd recommend using that value/calculation in the `$match` directly as the current approach would prevent the use of indexes

Comment: tried to calculate in match stage but no luck since $subtract gives output in milliseconds rather than isodate format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and found solutions below,

1. using **aggregate([])**:

   db.collectionName.aggregate([{$addFields:{difference:{$subtract:[new Date(),7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000]}}},{$match:{$expr:[$gte:"$createdDate","$difference"]}}}]);
2. using **find()**:

   db.collectionName.find({"createdDate":{$gt:new Date(new Date()-7*24*60*60*1000)}});

Answer (score 0):

A canonical way would be using `$dateSubtract` to compute 7 days before `$$NOW` and compare the result with `createdDaate` field.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gte": [
      "$createdDate",
      {
        "$dateSubtract": {
          "startDate": "$$NOW",
          "unit": "day",
          "amount": 7
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p5-HJzz-IzT)